# Как исправить анимацию pop-up?

Tags: html, jquery, css, popup

https://codepen.io/freeman0204/pen/BwWgeY

Подскажите, что не так с кодом jquery? При втором нажатии на одну и ту же ссылку появляется только overlay, самого окна нет. Правильно ли я создал структуру и стили для pop-up? Мне нужно сделать так, чтобы все нормально работало и при этом я смог задавать анимацию открытия и закрытия pop-up. Сейчас почти все работает. Но нужно поправить момент, о котором говорил выше. Как это сделать?

```js
$(".js-popup-trigger").on('click', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            $($(this).data("target")).css({
                "display" : "block"
            });
        });
    
    $(".close").on('click', function(){
            $(this).parent().animate({
                top : -200,
                opacity : 'toggle'
            }, 500);
            $(this).parents('.overlay').animate({
                opacity : 'toggle'
            }, 500);
        });
```

```css
.overlay {
      display: none;
      position: fixed;
      background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      z-index: 9999;
      left: 0;
      top: 0; 
    }
      .overlay .pop-up {
      font-family: circe-light;
      max-width: 420px;
      width: 100%;
      background-color: #ffffff;
      position: absolute;
      left: 50%;
      top: 50%;
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      margin: 10px;
      padding: 43px; 
    }
    .overlay .pop-up .close {
      position: absolute;
      right: 20px;
      top: 20px;
      background: url("data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABMAAAATCAYAAAByUDbMAAABDElEQVQ4T5XUyxGCMBAG4I0HHOFiCVqBloAdhEo840W4yNVOTAdSglagJXhBRw/ghkcGQh6EW4bJN7ubPyGAX0GzxIfvmbDkxdcuX0WT5Rvm+4DFKeEQbj4CVDcffjsXsIG8KwDZopGSVs5xsXEBJeiOnYWEt+QKKiEcUY25gDqIGwKbApqgEWYCbZASU4EzIFEJ1aU9tWbYihgN2uzna3go4o8W0lbWbf3QbFUCPLr1DGC9YPFTF2pLZSKQ3Zkbg63E5GFjRRQrZLZgjzDdqU0JtiJnorXRsG2gdAP00JSb0rubdsgGtq/GdMgIFvREMdmYbjAGUpUtaYZR3SYH8WHMXR7GYYVeGLAD+wOttQRILcfz3AAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==") no-repeat;
      width: 19px;
      height: 19px;
      transition: .5s; 
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="overlay js-popup-one">
        <div class="pop-up text-center">
            <div class="close"></div>
            <h3>Окно 1</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="overlay js-popup-two">
        <div class="pop-up text-center">
            <div class="close"></div>
            <h3>Окно 2</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <a href="" class="js-popup-trigger" data-target=".js-popup-one">Ссылка для открытия окна 1</a>
    
    <a href="" class="js-popup-trigger" data-target=".js-popup-two">Ссылка для открытия окна 2</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не работает всё это, потому что дело происходит так:

1. Оверлей имеет `display:none` и не отображается вместе с вложенными в него элементами.
2. После нажатия на ссылку оверлею присваивается `display:block`.
3. После скрытия элемента и оверлей, и попап получают `display:none`.
4. При повторном нажатии у оверлея становится стиль `display:block`, а у попапа так и остаётся `none`.

В общем, советую заглянуть в консоль разработчика и посмотреть, что там творится.

Чтобы это работало, советую вам показывать так же, как и скрывали:

```js
$(".js-popup-trigger").on('click', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            $($(this).data("target")).css({
                "display" : "block"
            });
            $($(this).data("target")).children(".pop-up").css({
                "display" : "block",
                "top" : "50%"
            });
        });
    
    $(".close").on('click', function(){
            $(this).parent().animate({
                top : -200,
                opacity : 'toggle'
            }, 500);
            $(this).parents('.overlay').animate({
                opacity : 'toggle'
            }, 500);
        });
```

```css
.overlay {
      display: none;
      position: fixed;
      background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      z-index: 9999;
      left: 0;
      top: 0; 
    }
      .overlay .pop-up {
      font-family: circe-light;
      max-width: 420px;
      width: 100%;
      background-color: #ffffff;
      position: absolute;
      left: 50%;
      top: 50%;
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      margin: 10px;
      padding: 43px; 
    }
    .overlay .pop-up .close {
      position: absolute;
      right: 20px;
      top: 20px;
      background: url("data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABMAAAATCAYAAAByUDbMAAABDElEQVQ4T5XUyxGCMBAG4I0HHOFiCVqBloAdhEo840W4yNVOTAdSglagJXhBRw/ghkcGQh6EW4bJN7ubPyGAX0GzxIfvmbDkxdcuX0WT5Rvm+4DFKeEQbj4CVDcffjsXsIG8KwDZopGSVs5xsXEBJeiOnYWEt+QKKiEcUY25gDqIGwKbApqgEWYCbZASU4EzIFEJ1aU9tWbYihgN2uzna3go4o8W0lbWbf3QbFUCPLr1DGC9YPFTF2pLZSKQ3Zkbg63E5GFjRRQrZLZgjzDdqU0JtiJnorXRsG2gdAP00JSb0rubdsgGtq/GdMgIFvREMdmYbjAGUpUtaYZR3SYH8WHMXR7GYYVeGLAD+wOttQRILcfz3AAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==") no-repeat;
      width: 19px;
      height: 19px;
      transition: .5s; 
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="overlay js-popup-one">
        <div class="pop-up text-center">
            <div class="close"></div>
            <h3>Окно 1</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="overlay js-popup-two">
        <div class="pop-up text-center">
            <div class="close"></div>
            <h3>Окно 2</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <a href="" class="js-popup-trigger" data-target=".js-popup-one">Ссылка для открытия окна 1</a>
    
    <a href="" class="js-popup-trigger" data-target=".js-popup-two">Ссылка для открытия окна 2</a>
```

Выглядит не очень красиво, но у меня не так много времени, и советов по структуре я не дам.

Comment: Спасибо, главное что работает. Дальше буду думать.